# Formatting information in a PHP recordset and setting it to an Array

Tags: php

I am attempting to use a Manager Class to take the results of a query and do formatting on pieces of information so I don't have to have logic on my view. I googled a number of solution and thought this would work, but my Array of Key=>values is coming back blank. Can someone take a look at it and see what i am doing wrong? Thanks!

I have verified that $results contains the values I am attempting to format and place back into an Array.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)){
    $pets[$row['petID']] = $row['petID'];
    $pets[$row['chipID']]=$row['chipID'];
    $pets[$row['adoptionDate']]=Date($row['adoptionDate'],'m-d-Y');
    $pets[$row['pType']]=$row['pType'];
    $pets[$row['breedName2']]=$row['breedName2'];
    $pets[$row['breedName1']]=$row['breedName1'];
    $pets[$row['imageName']]=$row['imageName'];
    $pets[$row['intakeDate']]= Date($row['intakeDate'],'m-d-Y');
    $pets[$row['status']]=$row['status'];
    $pets[$row['age']]=$row['age'];
    $pets[$row['ageText']]= $this->getAge($row['age']);
    $pets[$row['gender']]=$row['gender'];
    $pets[$row['genderText']] = $this->getGender($row['gender']);
    $pets[$row['breed2']]=$row['breed2'];
    $pets[$row['breed']]=$row['breed'];
    $pets[$row['petType']]=$row['petType'];
    $pets[$row['petName']]=$row['petName'];
    $pets[$row['customID']]=$row['customID'];
}
```

Here is the complete function that does not return anything:

```
public function getPets($cond,$orgID){

        $pets = array();
        $pg = new petsGateway();
        $results = $pg->listByQuery($cond, $orgID);

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)){
            $pets[$row['petID']] = $row['petID'];
            $pets[$row['chipID']]=$row['chipID'];
            $pets[$row['adoptionDate']]=Date($row['adoptionDate'],'m-d-Y');
            $pets[$row['pType']]=$row['pType'];
            $pets[$row['breedName2']]=$row['breedName2'];
            $pets[$row['breedName1']]=$row['breedName1'];
            $pets[$row['imageName']]= $this->getImageURL($row['imageName']);
            $pets[$row['intakeDate']]= Date($row['intakeDate'],'m-d-Y');
            $pets[$row['status']]=$row['status'];
            $pets[$row['age']]=$row['age'];
            $pets[$row['ageText']]= $this->getAge($row['age']);
            $pets[$row['gender']]=$row['gender'];
            $pets[$row['genderText']] = $this->getGender($row['gender']);
            $pets[$row['breed2']]=$row['breed2'];
            $pets[$row['breed']]=$row['breed'];
            $pets[$row['petType']]=$row['petType'];
            $pets[$row['petName']]=$row['petName'];
            $pets[$row['customID']]=$row['customID'];
        }
        return $pets;
    }
```

Comment: I do return pets at the bottom of the function but it keeps coming up blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hm.... well im not sure what you want, but as you have it now, the key and the value of your array will be the same, which makes it useless.

i.e. for petName
`$pets['Fido'] = 'Fido'`

probably you want to get rid of the `$row` portion of the left side of your assignment, so that you end up with this

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results))
{
    $pet = Array();

    $pet['petID']        = $row['petID'];
    $pet['chipID']       = $row['chipID'];
    $pet['adoptionDate'] = Date($row['adoptionDate'],'m-d-Y');
    $pet['pType']        = $row['pType'];
    $pet['breedName2']   = $row['breedName2'];
    $pet['breedName1']   = $row['breedName1'];
    $pet['imageName']    = $row['imageName'];
    $pet['intakeDate']   = Date($row['intakeDate'],'m-d-Y');
    $pet['status']       = $row['status'];
    $pet['age']          = $row['age'];
    $pet['ageText']      = $this->getAge($row['age']);
    $pet['gender']       = $row['gender'];
    $pet['genderText']   = $this->getGender($row['gender']);
    $pet['breed2']       = $row['breed2'];
    $pet['breed']        = $row['breed'];
    $pet['petType']      = $row['petType'];
    $pet['petName']      = $row['petName'];
    $pet['customID']     = $row['customID'];

    $pets.push($pet);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I am trying to set the key to the name in the '' and the value to the matching in the recordset. Also increment it due to their being many rows. My goal is this (very pseudo):

Row 1 = petID = 1, petName = 'Fluffy', status = 'Adopted', etc
Row 2 = petID = 2, petName = 'Barker', status = 'Available', etc
Row 3 = petID = 40, petName = 'Meowintons', status = 'Available', etc

Comment: By removing the row, will it just keep overwriting itself?

Comment: I think this is the closest I want. I am just looking to populate rows of data with modified data. Ok. So do I echo out row 0 of this above set on a page?

Comment: try it and see :) `print_var($pets[0])` should print out the first pet with all fields. though i would look into the answer provided by Marc B as well. Try some things yourself until you gain an understanding of what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

That's rather... repetitive code... wouldn't it be easier to modify your query to fetch the rows you want **AND** do the date formatting directly in the DB?

e.g.

```
SELECT rowID, ... DATE_FORMAT(adoptionDate, '%m-%d-%Y'), ...
FROM ...
```

and then

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   $pets[] = $row;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That will rewrite $pets[KEY] each time it loops through record. You want..

```
$pets[]['petID'] = $row['petID'];
$pets[]['chipID'] = $row['chipID'];
```

and so on

Comment: No, I dont want it overwrite, just add a new row. :)

Comment: The above as far as I can see should fix your issue. After the closing `}` add `print_r($pets);` to see the results

Comment: That means there's no results from your sql. I see your edit. You have class running inside a functions. I don't really know how that works so my help and input ends here I guess. I can recommend that you run your query on its own outside the function and class with `or die(mysql_error());` to see if there's any errors. Then see if there's results and then move into the function and class. :) good luck

Comment: Thanks for your help. It does return a value. I think I see part of the issue in not understanding how to create an associated Array in PHP. I think my next edit is closer to what I should be doing.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing but I understood that you want some thing like:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)){
    $pets[$row['petID']]['petID']        = $row['petID'];
    $pets[$row['petID']]['chipID']       = $row['chipID'];
    $pets[$row['petID']]['adoptionDate'] = Date($row['adoptionDate'],'m-d-Y');
    $pets[$row['petID']]['pType']        = $row['pType'];
    $pets[$row['petID']]['breedName2']   = $row['breedName2'];
    $pets[$row['petID']]['breedName1']   = $row['breedName1'];
    $pets[$row['petID']]['imageName']    = $row['imageName'];
    $pets[$row['petID']]['intakeDate']   = Date($row['intakeDate'],'m-d-Y');
    $pets[$row['petID']]['status']       = $row['status'];
    $pets[$row['petID']]['age']          = $row['age'];
    $pets[$row['petID']]['ageText']      = $this->getAge($row['age']);
    $pets[$row['petID']]['gender']       = $row['gender'];
    $pets[$row['petID']]['genderText']   = $this->getGender($row['gender']);
    $pets[$row['petID']]['breed2']       = $row['breed2'];
    $pets[$row['petID']]['breed']        = $row['breed'];
    $pets[$row['petID']]['petType']      = $row['petType'];
    $pets[$row['petID']]['petName']      = $row['petName'];
    $pets[$row['petID']]['customID']     = $row['customID'];
}
```

This way you have an array with all the pets ID as first key and its details in the second key. You can use the array push as well.